# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str, when using MTCNN

Tags: python, opencv

I´m getting below error when I want to access the following tupple

[{'box': [215, 102, 179, 238],
'confidence': 0.999460756778717,
'keypoints': {'left_eye': (277, 193),
'mouth_left': (287, 284),
'mouth_right': (356, 283),
'nose': (330, 239),
'right_eye': (361, 191)}}]

```
for person in face_locations:
bounding_box = person['box']   #in this line I get the error
keypoints = person['keypoints']



cv2.rectangle(img_final,
              (bounding_box[0], bounding_box[1]),
              (bounding_box[0]+bounding_box[2], bounding_box[1] + bounding_box[3]),
              (0,155,255),
              2)
cv2.circle(img_final,(keypoints['left_eye']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
cv2.circle(img_final,(keypoints['right_eye']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
cv2.circle(img_final,(keypoints['nose']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
cv2.circle(img_final,(keypoints['mouth_left']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
cv2.circle(img_final,(keypoints['mouth_right']), 2, (0,155,255), 2)
```

Comment: the code should work properly with the correct identation. you should check if for every object inside face_locations you have the error. may be you are not getting the data from the correct place, or may be some previous error is giving you a tuple instead of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
for person in face_locations:
bounding_box = person['box']   
keypoints = person['keypoints']
```

You should do this:

```
person = face_locations[0]
bounding_box = person['box']
keypoints = person['keypoints']
print(bounding_box, keypoints)
```

**result:**

```
 [`215, 102, 179, 238]`

{'left_eye': (277, 193), 'mouth_left': (287, 284), 'mouth_right': (356, 283), 'nose': (330, 239), 'right_eye': (361, 191)}
```